# Cypress contains ignores elements

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, testing, cypress

I want to find a clickable element using [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). The clickable element always includes the text "Login" and is inside the container div. However, the catch is that I don't know if the clickable element is modeled using an `<button>`, `<a>`, or `<input type="submit">`.

My HTML sometimes look like this:

```
<nav>
  <button>Wrong Login Button</button>
</nav>
<div class='container'>
  ...
  <div>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    ...
    <button>Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And sometimes like this example:

```
<div class='container'>
  ...
  <div>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    ...
    <div>
        <div>
          <a>Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is sometimes a `<button>`, sometimes a `<a>` or `<input type="submit">`. And sometimes there are also more nested divs in there.

**How can I find the clickable element (button, a or submit) element using cypress?**

I only want to find the clickable element, so if there is a heading with the text "Login", it should be ignored.

This is nearly the answer:

```
cy.get('.container').contains('Login')
```

However, I somehow need to ignore all elements other than (button, a, and input[type=submit]). Because otherwise it would return the

### Login

I need something like:

```
cy.get('.container').find('button OR a OR input[type=submit]').contains('Login')
```

I thought of writing a custom command that can be used as the example below:

```
cy.get('.container').findClickable('Login')
```

The implementation could look similar as the example below:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('findClickable', {prevSubject: ['element']}, (
    subject: Cypress.Chainable<HTMLElement>,
    text: string,
    options?: Partial<Cypress.Loggable & Cypress.Timeoutable & Cypress.Withinable & Cypress.Shadow>,
) => {
  const buttons = cy.wrap(subject).find('button').contains(text)
  const links = cy.wrap(subject).find('a').contains(text)
  const submits = cy.wrap(subject).find('input[type=submit]').contains(text)

  if (buttons.length + links.length + submits.length !== 1) {
    throw new DOMException(
        `Didn't find exactly one element. Found ${buttons.length} buttons, ${links.length} links, and ${submits.length} submits.`)
  }

  if (buttons.length === 1)
    return buttons[0]
  else if (links.length === 1)
    return links[0]
  else
    return submits[0]
})
```

I know that the code above does not work because of many reasons. First, there is no .length attribute and second, cypress would fail because of the timeout of the first find('buttons') method.

Does anyone know how to implement the custom command the right way?

Comment: Add the HTML for your element.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that!

Comment: Do you have just one `Login` button on the webpage ?

Comment: No, there is a second one in the navbar, but the navbar is not in the container div. So, I only have one Login button in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to search for multiple selectors when separating them with a comma:

```
cy.get('button, a, input[type=submit]')
```

So, search for all clickable elements and then filter for the clickable elements containing the required text.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('findClickable', {prevSubject: ['element']}, (
    subject: Cypress.Chainable<HTMLElement>,
    text: string,
    _options?: Partial<Cypress.Loggable & Cypress.Timeoutable & Cypress.Withinable & Cypress.Shadow>,
) =>
  cy.wrap(subject)
      .find('button, a, input[type=submit]')
      .filter(':contains(' + text + ')'),
)
```

Usage:

```
cy.get('.container').findClickable('Login')
```

Comment: I think it only works when all the elements you want are static.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach only works when the **elements are already loaded** (as mentioned in Muffy's comment).

The [multiple selectors operator](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector) returns as soon as any selector is found.

So, from your example, using `.find('button, a, input[type=submit]')` might incorrectly select `<button>Wrong Login Button</button>` if it happens that `<button>Login</button>` is still loading.

Instead, merge `:contains()` into the multiple selector operator like this

```js
button:contains(Login), a:contains(Login), input[type=submit]:contains(Login)
```

This will be more specific about which button and give you a reliable test under asynchronous page loading.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('findClickable', {prevSubject: ['element']}, (subject, text, options) => {

  const selectors = ['button', 'a', 'input[type=submit]']
  const selectorsWithText = selectors.map(s => `${s}:contains(${text})`)

  cy.wrap(subject).find(selectorsWithText, options)
})

cy.get('.container').findClickable('Login', {timeout:6_000)
```

---

#### Just using :contains() selector

If text just appears on the clickable element,  `:contains()` can be used without the multiple selectors (but watch out for labels and headings with same text)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('findClickable', {prevSubject: ['element']}, (subject, text, options) => {

  const selector = `:contains(${text})`  // any element with text "Login"
  cy.wrap(subject).find(selector, options)
})

cy.get('.container').findClickable('Login', {timeout:6_000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `within` and `contains` command with a combination of selector and text.

```js
cy.get('.container').within(() => {
  cy.contains('button', 'Login').click()
  cy.get('input[type=submit]').click()
  cy.contains('Login').click()
})
```

For Multiple Login, First we are checking the button is enabled or disabled, then we are clicking on it.

```js
cy.contains('Login').each(($ele) => {
  if($ele.is(":enabled")){
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
  }
})
```

You can also do, this is a more optimized code for the above snippet.

```js
cy.contains('Login').filter(':enabled').click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But, it would only work for buttons, not for a, or input[type=submit], right? I have added another HTML example. My code has to work for both examples.

Comment: It will work for any `cy.get` command as well. Updated my answer.

Comment: Your code works if the element exists. But, only one of these three elements is on the page: button, a or <input type=submit/>. And I don't know which one.

Comment: But will the Text be same that is `Login` irrespective of element type a or button or submit ?

Comment: So, if the page looks like this: <button>Login</button> my code should find the button and if the page looks like this:  <a>Login</a> my code should find the a element.

Comment: Yes, the text is always "Login"

Comment: Then you can use `cy.contains('Login').click()`, just the text. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That is nearly the answer! But, what if the HTML looks like: <span>Login</span><button>Login</button>? I only want the clickable elements. In this case the button

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the current question. I would suggest you to create a new question for this.

Comment: But, that was exactly the thing I am trying to ask. I think I described it badly. I will change the question.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Can I also check the element type instead of checking if it is enabled? If you answer this I will give you the green check :)

Comment: I suggest you read up on [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), it's the way Cypress finds elements. The [MDN page for selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) has some usefull examples. Then you can use the first code-block in this answer and tweak it to your liking.